# Branch and Bound VRP has zero nodes

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gurobi, operations-research

I'am trying to solve the VRP with Gurobi and therefore analyse the branch-and-bound tree, but Gurobi solves the problem in the root and doesn't use branch-and-bound (0 nodes explored). Is there a possibility to start the algorithm without presolving?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off presolving using the [Presolve parameter](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/presolve.html).

However, note that your problem may still be solved in the root node; branching is only necessary if you cannot find an optimal integral solution in the root node.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responce! Is it a problem with my constraints, because I think the VRP is normally solved in a branch-and-bound and in numerous nodes?                                                   Edit: I use the Cordeau instance with 100 customers and the solution is the same, as the best solutions on the internet, so my formulation should be okay.

Comment: I don't know about your specific instances, but I think you're misunderstanding something about how the VRP is solved in general and how linear programming works. Branch and bound may not be necessary if you find an integral and optimal solution in the root node (which closes the gap), which can happen when using cutting planes or pricing, where the latter is often the case for VRP problems.
I am not sure how you have implemented it / how Gurobi handles it, which would help me point out to you why this could be the case. Could you perhaps post the data of the run?

Comment: I read about branch-and-bound beeing the most used algorithm to solve the VRP. The cutting plane uses e.g. the simplex method right? Here is a MediaFire link with the MPS file, I use. [https://www.mediafire.com/file/tkv8d18j3mol33k/Sol_100_C101.mps/file]

Comment: I have implented it like this: [https://www.mediafire.com/file/5cwvxjyyllbqlux/VRP.txt/file] I hope the links work!

Comment: MILP solvers like gurobi are complex; there's a lot of methodologies. In particular, the problem you're working with is well known and can be quite complex. There is a *lot* of literature that has been studied which tries to overcome this. In particular [cutting plane methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting-plane_method) and [pricing methods using Dantzig Wolfe Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dantzig%E2%80%93Wolfe_decomposition) are common in literature. I don't know how smart Gurobi is in this case, but I would not be suprised if it would apply some of these tricks here.

Comment: Without seeing Gurobi's debug output on your instance, it will be difficult to help you since you only specify the model, and let gurobi figure out the solution methods.

Comment: I used the default solver on Gurobi and also changed the method to primal Simplex (params.method=0) and to barrier (params.method=2). In these cases Gurobi solves the problem with these solvers, as it says in the output, even though there is no branch-and-bound tree. Because of that I assumed that the solving in the rooting node is done with simplex or barrier etc. Here is my output of Gurobi: [https://www.mediafire.com/folder/kvcflx5f7n8n1/Gurobi]

Comment: It seems like gurobi uses cutting planes to determine that the solution is optimal in all of the runs you do. You could turn these off by adjusting the [Cuts parameter](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/cuts.html) to 0. In this case, Gurobi will use a branch-and-bound approach only (combined with other options such as heuristics)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Gurobi is still solving the problem in the root node with my different parameters (prim Simplex, dual Simplex, Barrier) and no branch-and-bound. But I think in this case, it is not possible to call the branch-and-bound and it seems to be not necessary either.